# Python current working directoy set to home path instead of script dir

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, visual-studio-code

Why don't I get a json file written to disk in the current working directory (script location) when executing the following script? Shouldn't dump() do this?

```
def getShotFolders():
    shotDict = {
        "root" : shotExample,
        "shot_subdirs" : []
    }  
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(shotExample, topdown=False):
        if root != shotExample:
            shotDict["shot_subdirs"].append(os.path.relpath(root,shotExample))

    pprint(shotDict)
    with open("shot_folderStructure.json", "w") as write_file: 
        json.dump(shotDict, write_file )

getShotFolders()
```

EDIT: Ok, I run my python files from vscode with right click 'execute python file in terminal' which outputs the `C:/Python27/python.exe c:/Users/user/Desktop/test.py` command.

If I run the script from pycharm with the same python set as the project interpreter the json files are created, but why?

EDIT2: ok for some reason when I execute the script the cwd is my home folder, shouldn't it be to the path of the python script. I know this can be fixed by `os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))` but it shouldn't be this way right?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are opening your `C:\Users\user\Desktop` folder in VS Code in order to set the cwd to your desktop (if you open the file directly then it won't change your working directory).